# module not found for angularx-social-login

Tags: angular

I have this errors compiling simple app for FB and Google login:

```
ERROR in /home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login/angularx-social-login.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login'
ERROR in /home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login/angularx-social-login.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login'
ERROR in /home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login/angularx-social-login.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs' in '/home/andrea/node_modules/angularx-social-login'
```

I've installed angularx-social-login module and run npm install.I've followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login What can I do?

Comment: Could you please post the code, where you import the `angularx-social-login` and the `angular` modules?

Comment: I solved. I rebooted the system. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -f angularx-social-login` worked for me

Comment: This worked excelent for me!

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me. Precisely with the new version. But I noticed that in the npm documentation it imports the 'angularx-social-login' but it should be '@abacritt/angularx-social-login'.
Solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save angularx-social-login
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install angular-6-social-login
```